# How to transfer image and data between components | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, jsx

In the project I have a Upload image component that asks the user for an image and then previews it on the page. The image is not persay "uploaded" to any server and I hope that it does'nt need to. The goal is to be able to compare this uploded image with a random active set of images from an API (`Image.js`). What I have problem with is how to use the `previewImage: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])`  inside of another file, or at least that is what I belive to be the right way to think about it. *(For context: The idea is to check the correlation between the uploaded file and the random active set.)*

I have tried to implement an child to child state transfer but gave up when it did not work for the child to parent part. `App.js` is the parent,  `Image.js` and `image-upload.component.js` are the children. I have also looked for ways to solve this with redux but don't understand how to store images or utilize states inside of the store. For this i only need to update the image state when files are selected by user.

**To somewhat summarize and clarify the question**: How can I transfer the chosen image file between two components and use the data in both of them?

This is my first project in React so the code may be caotic and full of "brute force" so I apologice in advance for that. Any help or guidence is greatly appreciated!

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import UploadImages from "./components/image-upload.component";
import Images from "./components/Images";




function App() {



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-5">
            <div className="content"> 
            <h3>Title</h3> 
            <h4>Upload my picture here</h4>
            <UploadImages/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-2">
          </div>
          <div className="col-5">
              <Images />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Images.js (pure, brute force code i guess):

```
import UploadImages from "./image-upload.component";

import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import "./Images.css";



function shuffleArray(array) {
  let i = array.length - 1;
  for (; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

function Images() {

  const [urls, setURLs] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] =useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [
      250940,
      20622,
      436625,
      436444,
      436509,
      359245,
      459090,
      333933,
      333916,
      466350,
      44831,
      383010,
      202660,
      406317,
      337349,
      503448,
      12617,
      248662,
      435805,
      438545
    ].map(
      (itemId) =>
        `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${itemId}`
    );
    shuffleArray(urls)
    Promise.all(
      urls.map((currUrl) =>
        fetch(currUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => data.primaryImage)
          .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
      )
    ).then((fetchedUrls) => setURLs(fetchedUrls));
  }, []);



  if (count === 3) {
    return (
    <div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[1]} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[2]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[3]} alt=""  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      onClick={() => setCount(4)}>
      Next
    </button>
    </div>
    )
  }


  if (count === 4) {
    return (
    <div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[1]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[2]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[3]} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[4]}  alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      onClick={() => setCount(3)}>
      Previous
    </button>
    <button
      onClick={() => setCount(5)}>
      Next
    </button>
    </div>
    )
  }


  if (count === 5) {
    return (
    <div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[1]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[2]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[3]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[4]} alt=""  />
      </div>
      <div class="images__item">
        <img class="photo" src={urls[5]} alt=""  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      onClick={() => setCount(4)}>
      Previous
    </button>
    <button
      onClick={() => {setCount(3); shuffleArray(urls);}}>
      Reset
    </button>
    </div>
    )
  }


  else {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <UploadImages upsideEmit={getStateFromChild} /> */}
          <button
              onClick={() => {shuffleArray(urls); setCount(3);}}>
          Open
          </button>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default Images;
```

image-upload.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UploadService from "../services/file-upload.service";
import "./Images"


class UploadImages extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectFile = this.selectFile.bind(this);
    this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      currentFile: undefined,
      previewImage: undefined,
      progress: 0,
      message: "",
      imageInfos: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UploadService.getFiles().then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        imageInfos: response.data,
      });
    });
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentFile: event.target.files[0],
      previewImage: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
      message: ""
    });
  }

  upload() {
    this.setState({
      progress: 0,
    });
    UploadService.upload(this.state.currentFile, (files) => {
        this.setState({
          imageInfos: files.data,
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      previewImage,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-8">
            <label className="btn btn-default p-0">
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={this.selectFile} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className="col-4">
          </div>
        </div>
        

        {previewImage && (
          <div>
            <img className="preview" src={previewImage} alt="" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default UploadImages
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you would want to useContext hook for this.

Check out this tutorial https://dev.to/email2vimalraj/react-hooks-lift-up--pass-down-state-using-usecontext-and-usereducer-5ai0

Comment: It seemes like i cant use a react hook inside a a Class. 
it gives me the error: "React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function" when I try to apply it to my class

Comment: Ah.. You would set up the context in you App (which is a component).  This article may help with accessing from a class you would use a static like so:

class UploadImages extends Component {
static contextType = MyContext